# How to create a custom list in Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, blend

I am new to Blend and WPF and I'd like to have a control that has ListBox sort of properties but with my own custom items. Essentially, I want each item to be a rounded off rectangle with a label. The first way I thought was by using a UserControl and StackPanel, although I couldn't think of how to tell the program which object(s) have focus. For this reason, I thought that I could use a ListBox and hence make a custom ListBoxItem, but obviously only the rectangle could be converted to the control, losing the label.. Any pointers would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ListBox and you're not limited to just the rectangle and not the label.

Use a standard ListBox, and make ListBox.ItemTemplate as complex as you like.  If you need to layer a bunch of controls on top of each other, you can start with a Canvas or Grid control and go from there.

Alternately, you could just make the item template a single Label control (if logically the item behaves as a label), and use a ControlTemplate to completely redo the visual tree rendered for those labels.

References:

1. [ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [ControlTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here's a quick example.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Labels}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="CadetBlue" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Label Content="{Binding}" Padding="10"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The "ViewModel":

```
    public IEnumerable<string> Labels
    {
        get { return new string[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz" }; }
    }
```

And the result:

[image: Output]